# JSF value not refreshed - Browser Caching?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I do have a strange problem with my JSF application.

I have a `ViewScoped` bean. When I load my page with IE11 it displays value `A` from my database. Now in the background another user updates this value to `B`. The other use refreshes the page but he still gets value `A` displayed despite the fact that `B` is now in the database.

When I open the same page using Firefox, `B` is displayed as expected. When I press F5 in IE11 it is still `A`.

Could it be possible that the IE11 caches my page? I  know that I can disable browser caching but I am not sure if it will impact the performance.

Comment: This question is quite broadly put and you're not really looking to the problem as a developer, but more as an enduser. Please elaborate the problem more in developer's perspective. E.g., to exclude one and other, can you confirm the described behavior by checking HTTP traffic monitor (cached or not) and debugging bean's getter method (if invoked, is it same or different bean)?

Comment: okay I tackled down the problem a little bit. We have cluster with 2 instances. On the one instance it is displayed correctly. But on the other instance it displays the old value. Hm... wondering how I can fix this